# Does the present simple have future meaning in these sentences?

Tags: tense, present-tense, future-constructions

According to [my grammar book](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/a-students-introduction-to-english-grammar/EB0ABC6005935012E5270C8470B2B740#overview) (a student's version of CaGel) the present tense is used in English for future events that are planned/already known. Based on this, am I correct in assuming that the (a) and (b) alternatives below are equally correct and idiomatic?

1 a) Auditions **take place** every other Saturday

b) Auditions **will take place** every other Saturday

2 a) Each contract **is accompanied** by a contract supplement

b) Each contract **will be accompanied** by a contract supplement

3 a) All pupils **meet** with the career counsellor in their last year of school

b) All pupils **will meet** with the career counsellor in their last year of school

Comment: The (a) sentences are correct, not because they refer to planned future events, but because they describe routine events. The construction you are thinking of is "I fly to Rome next Saturday" and similar.

Comment: @KateBunting yes, exactly – these are slightly different; that's why I was wondering whether these too fall under this rule :) I take it they don't then, but rather that they are explained by the present tense being used for routines?

Comment: Yes. The auditions are already taking place on alternate Saturdays, and similarly with the other examples.

Comment: They are all fine. Syntactically, the modal auxiliary verb "will" has two tenses: present and preterite. Semantically, it is used to make reference to future time (about 80% of its occurrences, I believe).  For example, "The film will be seen at the Sundance festival" is syntactically a present tense clause with "will" as the tensed verb. But in that example, "will" clearly expresses reference to future time --- something that could be done in various other ways as well ("The film is going to be seen at the Sundance festival," "The film is about to be seen at the Sundance festival," etc.).

Comment: Without context, (a) and (b) have different meanings.  1a sounds like auditions are already ongoing every Saturday, and 1b sounds like they haven't started yet.  The distinction strikes me as subtler in 2 and still subtler in 3.  Context could probably override my initial impression to some extent.

Comment: Also, is your book referring to the "ing" version of the present tense?  That is very common to express planned future events: "I'm auditioning for a play" would mean the audition is planned for the future (unless someone happens to say it in the middle of the audition).

Comment: @cruthers Interesting! I guess it's because (1) carries the least sense of something that is done as a routine, whereas (2) has a slightly stronger sense of routine, and (3) has a very strong sense of routine? As for the kind of present tense, I was thinking of the kind referred to by Kate Bunting in the first comment above – i.e. not the progressive.

Comment: @BillJ Can you give an example of "will" having a preterite tense?

Comment: @Helen, well, I was thinking in the case of (3), that this statement would typically be addressed to a group of incoming students at a school, informing them that they will meet the counselor in their last year.  In that case, 3a and 3b probably mean the same thing - it's an old routine and it will apply to them.  If, on the other hand, the statement were made as the school was being built and operations were being planned, 3a wouldn't make much sense but 3b would state the plans for the future routine.  I had a similar reaction for 2 - depends on whether the routine is established yet.

Comment: @gotube I think BillJ is thinking of "would", which would be the preterite tense of the verb "will" :)

Comment: @cruthers Yes – I see exactly what you mean :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they don't have the same meaning.

When the present simple has a future meaning, it is used for *scheduled* future events, like a train's departure time or a regular event:

> My train leaves *at 8:42 am*.
>
> I play in my hockey league *this Tuesday evening*.

Note the inclusion of the *future scheduled time*. Without the future time included somewhere in the context, there's no indication that it's about the future, so a sentence with simple present will have a present time meaning.

Your present simple example sentences (1a) and (3a) describe a currently repeating event. Sentence (2a) describes the current state of something.

"Will"-future has many functions in the future, but none of them refer specifically to scheduled events.

All three of your "will"-future sentences declare that something is going to happen in the future, and nothing more. They may be known or scheduled, or this may be their first announcement, or the moment someone decided that they are going to happen, all depending on the context.

Comment: Thank you! So, I could never use the (b) examples about something that is routinely done now, and that will continue to be routinely done in the future? Also, when it comes to 2a - couldn't that be used for a routine that applies now, and that will continue applying in the future, for future contracts? So that 2a could have the meaning 'contracts have always been, are, and will always be accompanied by a supplement'?

Comment: @Helen You're welcome! I'll rephrase what you said: "You could never use the (b) examples **to mean** that something is routinely done now, and will continue to be routinely done in the future." You could, however, use it **about** those things because they will happen in the future, at least once, and that's all "will" means on its own.

Comment: @Helen Similarly, 2a on its own says nothing about whether this is a regular process, just that this is how it will happen **this time**. In the right context, it could imply that this is the way **going forward** by inferring it means, "... will **from now on**...". "Will" cannot have any meaning about the past, like "have always been"